# Prolog not operator

Tags: prolog

Given the following facts, what do the following 2 queries output:

```
p(a).
p(b).

q(c).

?- not p(X), q(X).
?- q(X), not p(X).
```

For me, both of these requests failed, but apparently the second one succeeds with X=c. I can't tell if there's something wrong with the answer key to this problem, or it's my Prolog, or just something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try `\+` instead of `not`.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized some of the answers in these solutions are not even in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: *For me, both of these requests failed, but apparently the second one succeeds with `X=c`.*. What do you mean by this? Are you saying that the second expression failed for you, not even succeeding with `X = c`?

Comment: `not/1` is specific to some Prologs such as SWI, but the correct ISO operator is `\+` and it means *not provable*. If you have a set of asserted facts for `p/1` and you query `\+ p(X)`, this succeeds if `p(X)` is *not provable*. `\+ p(e)` for example would succeed. However, `p(X)` is provable because Prolog will find at least one `X` that makes it true, so in the expression `\+ p(X), q(X)`,  `\+ p(X)` fails before it even attempts `q(X)` and the entire query fails.

Comment: For the second case, `q(X)` succeeds with `X=c`, then Prolog attempts to determine if `p(X)` (which is now `p(c)`) is not provable, and it turns out it is not provable (there is no factor or rule that allows `p(c)` to succeed), so the entire query succeeds with `X = c`.